# How to hook up C wire to Crown air handler

Tags: thermostat, thermostat-c-wire, nest

Sorry for the newbie question, but I would like to hook up a C wire so that I can get a Nest, Ecobee, etc.  My current thermostat is just a regular battery operated Honeywell and looking at the current thermostat wire, I have the extra blue/brown wires available, but they aren't being used and not connected to anything.  I looked at the control board at the handler and there already is a wire on the C terminal going to the air conditioner condenser outside.

In the picture below - the top red (R), white (W), green (G), yellow (Y) and the unconnected brown/blue wires are going back to the thermostat .  The middle white (C) and red (YR) wires go to the condenser.

I assume I need to connect the blue wire from the thermostat to the C, but what do I do with the existing white wire that is already connected?   Can both of the wires go on that terminal?

I also attached the wiring diagram for my air handler

[image: control board picture]

[image: wiring diagram]

Answer (score 1):

1. Get a scrap bit of wire, that's the same thickness as the other wires.
2. Disconnect the wire that is currently in the `C` terminal.
3. Strip both ends of the scrap piece of wire.
4. Connect one end of the scrap piece of wire to the `C` terminal.
5. Using a twist-on wire connector (or other connector), connect the wire that was previously connected to the `C` terminal with the new `C` wire, and the other end of the scrap bit of wire.

When finished, the two `C` wires should be connected together, along with the wire that's connected to the `C` terminal.

This type of connection is known as a "*pigtail*".